# Creating Wordpress admin panel for premium theme without a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress admin panel for a premium theme and I don't want to use a plugin. Searched Google and StackOverflow a lot but everywhere it refers to the Settings API but checking the date of the articles or question/answer posted date, majority shows 2012 or early. I checked some premium themes of themeforest and none of them were using any of the Settings API functions such as `add_settings_section`, `register_setting`, `add_settings_field`. Each theme is using a different and specific way to save admin panel options, if I follow that then that will be a copy of that theme.

Is Settings API the right solution for this requirement?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Customizer - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

This will work fine if you're only talking about a few settings - you can add new panels, inputs etc. For example on a theme I built, I added a 'contact' panel so the users can add their contact details.

Comment: Customizer is not user friendly. I would like to add the menu/submenus to the normal left menu bar or Wordpress and I am thinking of covering a lot of the options. Majority of the premium themes are not using customizer